# Difference between "Accept" and "Final Decision Accept"

Tags: journals, paper-submission

We have submitted a manuscript to a reputable BMC journal. A few days ago, we received a mail stating that our article was accepted. In the Editorial Manager software, it says " accept " under "current status". Our previously submitted manuscripts to that particular journal have the status "Final Decision Accept". May I ask whether there is any difference between "final decision accept" and "accept"? I am asking since the field "final deposition" is still empty for our recent article.

Answer (score 2):

"Final Decision Accept" is a weirder way of saying "Accept". Congratulations.

Comment: I know my question may sound stupid but I heard that "accept" is something conditional whereas final decision accept is not?

Comment: @Dr.M This is going to depend on the specifics of how the individual journals administer themselves. Often when the editor clicks 'accept', the decision is not instantly communicated to the authors. Instead various internal processes happen first: some journals may send the decision to another editor (or the Chief Editor) for approval; in others there may be administrative processes that take place before the decision is sent out. Technically it's not final until it's final, but in the majority of cases the decision will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are "Accept" is when the editorial board member handling the paper recommends acceptance, and "Final decision: accept" is when the editor-in-chief formally accepts the paper.

Congrats!